# How to tweet images, replies and retweet with tweepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I have a small script (not created by me) in python to tweet, in this way however I can only tweet text, there is a way to also tweet images, videos, retweets and replies. The script work with tweepy

Here is the script:

```py
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("API KEY", "API SECRET") 
auth.set_access_token("ACCESS TOKEN", "ACCESS TOKEN SECRET") 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweet = input("What Would You Like To Tweet? ")
api.update_status(status =(tweet))
print ("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to tweet images, videos, retweets etc. indeed you need other functions of the api to call (otherwise how it could differ between different commands?)

You need the checkout the [tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html) to get comprehensive answers but:

[**Tweet with Media**](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.update_with_media):

```
filename = "image_to_be_sent.png"
status = "Hello World!"
api.update_with_media(filename = filename, status = status)
```

[**Retweet**:](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.retweet)

```
api.retweet(id) # you should now the tweet id you want to retweet
```

**Reply**:

In order to reply you can use either `api.update_status()` or `api.update_with_media()` depending on if, you want to attach an image or video or not. You should only set the optional argument `in_reply_to_status_id`.

e.g:

```
filename = "image_to_be_sent.png"
status = "Hello World!"
api.update_with_media(filename = filename, status = status, in_reply_to_status_id = in_reply_to_status_id)
```

Comment: Isn't `update_with_media` deprecated? It says so in their docs.

Comment: Oh That's true. In version 3.9.0 it is deprecated.